# Не получается вставить запрос с параметрами

Tags: c#, postgresql

У меня есть структура объявленная в отдельном файле. Мне нужно заполнить ее данными из одной БД и вставить в другую, однако упорно вылетает ошибка с типами. Подозреваю, что синтаксис запроса с параметрами не верен.

```
string SQLrequest = @"SELECT id, guid, username, userblob FROM ""USERS""";
NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand(SQLrequest, conn);

try
{

    NpgsqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader(); // here exception
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        // UserData ud = new UserData();
        ud.id = dr[0].ToString();
        ud.guid = (dr[1].ToString());
        ud.name = (dr[2].ToString());
        ud.userblob = (byte[]) dr[3];

    }
    dr.Dispose(); // releases conenction

}
```

Вроде бы все верно, или я в чем-то ошибаюсь?

```
       public void insertDataFromPGToSQLLite(UserData ud)
    {

       SQLiteConnection m_dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + config.SQLLitePath + ";Version=3;");
       m_dbConnection.Open();

       SQLiteCommand insertSQL = new SQLiteCommand("INSERT INTO test01.USERS id, guid, name, userblob) VALUES (?,?,?,?)", m_dbConnection);
       try
       {

        insertSQL.Parameters.Add(ud.id);
        insertSQL.Parameters.Add(ud.guid);
        insertSQL.Parameters.Add(ud.name);
        insertSQL.Parameters.Add(ud.userblob);

          Console.WriteLine("!!!");
          insertSQL.ExecuteNonQuery();
          Console.WriteLine("DONE");
      }

      catch (Exception e)
      {
          Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);

      }

      finally
      {
          m_dbConnection.Close();
      }

    }
```

[image: Запрос с параметрами Insert]

Answer (score 2):

А как по мне, то проблема в добавлении параметров, как прямо и ругается в консоли.

Нужно ведь писать:

```
insertSQL.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter(....));
```

[А вот, собственно, описание](https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/sqlite/docs/Devart.Data.SQLite~Devart.Data.SQLite.SQLiteParameter~_ctor.html).

Comment: точно. Только ссылка скорее: https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/sqlite/docs/Devart.Data.SQLite~Devart.Data.SQLite.SQLiteParameterCollection~Add(Object).html

Comment: Согласен-просто давал описание конструкторов-не дописал...

Comment: Пробовал сделать так:  `insertSQL.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter(ud.userblob, DbType.Byte));` но у меня же массив `byte[]` а так мне судия ввести не предлагает.

Comment: @Suliman `SQLiteType.Blob`

Answer (score 1):

`"INSERT INTO test01.USERS id, guid, name, userblob) VALUES (?,?,?,?)"`

Пропущена "(", открывающая список полей.

`"INSERT INTO test01.USERS (id, guid, name, userblob) VALUES (?,?,?,?)"`